# Beamer overlay only/visible

Tags: beamer, overlays

I am trying to change a formula between two slides. Here is an MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
Something before\\
\bigskip
$%
B\left(%
\only<1>{A_2[i]}%
\only<2>{A_L[i]}%
\right) =%
\only<1>{C_1 + C_2}%
\visible<2>{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{L} C_k}%
\quad \text{text here }%
\only<1>{a,b,c,}%
\only<2>{a,b,c,\ldots,z}
$

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, there is a problem with the position of "text here" in the first slide. If I put `only` instead of `visible`, that problem is solved but then everything moves during the transition. Is there a way to solve both issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `\vphantom` is useful in this case. It will reserve the vertical space required by the sum and prevent "wobbling" of the formula during overlays.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
Something before\\
\bigskip
$%
B\left(%
\only<1>{A_2[i]}%
\only<2>{A_L[i]}%
\right) =%
\only<1>{C_1 + C_2 \vphantom{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{L} C_k}}%
\only<2>{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{L} C_k}%
\quad \text{text here }%
\only<1>{a,b,c,}%
\only<2>{a,b,c,\ldots,z}
$

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. So I learned a new command: `vphantom`: maybe one day I will know them all... Thank you!

Comment: What about horizontal space?  The `text here a,b,c` still moves left and right...

Comment: @Alex For horizontal spacing you can do the same with `\hphantom`